# Does ruby have similiar multidimensional array like in php?

Tags: php, arrays, ruby

like in php:

```
$input = [
      'a' => 'A',
      'b' => 'B',
      'cdef' => [
             'c' => 'C',
             'd' => 'D',
             'ef' => [
                  'e' => 'E',
                  'f' => 'F'
             ]
      ]
]
```

maybe use Hash? never used ruby before :)

When I worte code:

```
input = Hash.new
input['a'] = 'A'
input['b'] = 'B'
input['cdef']['c'] = 'C'
input['cdef']['d'] = 'D'
input['cdef']['ef']['e'] = 'E'
input['cdef']['ef']['f'] = 'F'
```

error at

```
  input['cdef']['c'] = 'C'
```

message :

```
[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: `input = { 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'cdef' => { 'c' => 'C', ... } }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the answer by @davidhu2000 is more or less correct, I would go with more robust solution: using [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) in the constructor. The `dup.clear` magic is to recursively pass the `default_proc` through to deeply nested elements:

```
input = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h.dup.clear }
input['a'] = 'A' 
input['b'] = 'B' 
input['cdef']['c'] = 'C' 
input['cdef']['d'] = 'D' 
input['cdef']['ef']['e'] = 'E' 
input['cdef']['ef']['f'] = 'F' 

input
```

That way one does not need ugly redundant assignments:

```
input['cdef'] = {}
input['cdef']['ef'] = {}
```

Ninja assignment:

```
input = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h.dup.clear }
input['a1']['a2']['a3']['a4']['a5'] = 42
input
#⇒ {"a1" => {"a2" => {"a3" => {"a4" => {"a5" => 42}}}}}
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks. It costs producing temporary redundant copy of the initial (and all nested having children) hash, though. But on human-operated hashes it should work fine.

Comment: @mudasobwa thx!... but how do I use this trick after I copy a clone of another multidimentional hash into `input`,like I have `origin = {'a'=>1,'b'=>2,'cd'=>{'c'=>3,'d'=>4}}`, and I copy origin into input,using `input = origin.clone`, then ur thick doesn't work,maybe `clone` operation has ruin the structure of input?

Comment: In the first place, please stop calling hashes “multidimentional arrays,” since they are not arrays by any means and php just implied a wrong usage of this term. Secondary, I did not understand the problem. As `origin` hash has `default_proc` declared, it’s clone has is either. The last, but not least: you should’ve asked another question on that, whether you have one.

Comment: f, I called it "multidimentional hash",since u haven't go through my question carefully with respect, I'm ok with it , s, thx, I know where the point is, lbnl, my question has not been solved, why can't I ask more, MDZZ

Comment: Indeed, there was a “multidimentional hash," nevertheless, it’s a plain old good “hash.” Please also use English, since there is not a chatroom for 14-yo cheerleaders. Your problem has been solved, now you have another one about cloning hashes—go ask it. SO is tended to implement a model 1 question per posting to make it easier for future readers to narrow their problem amongst the variety of already existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your error, you need to initialize an empty hash before assigning a key-value pair.

```
input = Hash.new
input['a'] = 'A'               #=> {"a"=>"A"}
input['b'] = 'B'               #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B"}
input['cdef'] = {}             #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "cdef"=>{}}
input['cdef']['c'] = 'C'       #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "cdef"=>{"c"=>"C"}}
input['cdef']['d'] = 'D'       #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "cdef"=>{"c"=>"C", "d"=>"D"}}
input['cdef']['ef'] = {}       #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "cdef"=>{"c"=>"C", "d"=>"D", "ef"=>{}}}
input['cdef']['ef']['e'] = 'E' #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "cdef"=>{"c"=>"C", "d"=>"D", "ef"=>{"e"=>"E"}}}
input['cdef']['ef']['f'] = 'F' #=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "cdef"=>{"c"=>"C", "d"=>"D", "ef"=>{"e"=>"E", "f"=>"F"}}}
```

Comment: I wonder how will assignment of nested element on level 10 look like with this approach. Please check my answer.

Comment: it'll be ugly, i definitely like your solution better.